# Output content of a node before and after a child element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I have the following xml file:

```
<parent> Hello
    <child>10</child>
    <child>20</child>
    <child>30</child
    Italic
    <child>400</child>
    <child>500</child>
    Bold
</parent>
```

Solution now:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
     <fo:block>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>         
      </fo:block>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child">
        <fo:inline>
            <fo:inline color="Red"><xsl:value-of select="child"/></fo:inline>
        </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

How can i output the content of the whole parent element and match the childs in any other format. I only get content before the first child Element (Hello).

expected output:
Hello 10 20 30 Italic 400 500 Bold (numbers in red)

output until now:
Hello

I use xslt 2.0. Thanks for helping

Comment: Could you please post your expected output.

Comment: ... and the output you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you use `apply-templates` to process child nodes, the rest falls into place, so change

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
     <fo:block>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>         
      </fo:block>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child">
        <fo:inline>
            <fo:inline color="Red"><xsl:value-of select="child"/></fo:inline>
        </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
     <fo:block>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>         
      </fo:block>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child">
        <fo:inline>
            <fo:inline color="Red">
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:inline>
        </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```